# At what throttle do I have the best maneuverability?

Tags: world-of-warships

If I want to turn my ship quickly to avoid things like islands that seem to suddenly appear or torpedos coming to hurt me, what is the best throttle to do so?

Ships behave very differently from cars and such where moving slow makes you turn better, but If you go fast, you can't turn that sharp either. Should I try for somewhere in the middle, does it depend on the ship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not the turn radius of a ship is not effected by the speed of the ship and so there isn't necessarily a "best throttle" to complete such a turn. Essentially the turning radius at full throttle is pretty much the same as the turning circle at half throttle. The throttle will only effect the speed in which the turn is completed. Therefore when avoiding torps I tend to go into a turn at full throttle.

[There's a good blog which explains how the game mechanics for ships movement works in WOWs here](http://blog.worldofwarships.eu/full-speed-ahead/)

If you miss the warning for torps and it's too late to turn you're probably best to just drastically drop your speed so hopefully you wont be hit by the full spread.

Comment: that blog was written like 2 years ago while the game was still under heavy development, is it still relevant?

Comment: I haven't seen anything mentioned that would countermand it and this recent [forum post](http://forum.worldofwarships.eu/index.php?/topic/10230-speed-and-turns/) would seem to confirm the assertions.